# Issue in Implementing Facebook Share Button Functionality

Tags: facebook, share

On Implementing the Facebook Share Button on my Web Application, the "Public Button" is misplaced.Instead "Public" button should be beside "Share" button. But it gets displayed on top of the Pop Up Window. Also when we click the Arrow key beside Public, options are displayed partially.

Actually I am trying to upload the image to show the exact issue but I am getting the error that "There should be atleast 10 reputations to upload". Not able to understand why?

**But Let me explain the issue with more details.** I am using the code to implement the FBShare Button functionality. Hence using the link **"facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php"**; in my javascript. If you hit this link the button which gives us the option to Share the content either Public,Friends,Only Me,Custom...etc. is placed at the top of the pop up rather than it should be beside "Share" button.

Comment: Hey Finally today when i hit **facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php** the  button which gives us the option to Share the content either Public,Friends,Only Me,Custom...etc...displays the value at the right corner now with proper values.Thank God It is resolved.